# Contextual links for main menu

Tags: routes, navigation, views

Hello Drupal enthusiasts,

any idea why in my theme I cannot see that gear icon with contextual links for left menu? Module enabled, I see them for views and blocks used in Panels. But in left menu, where main navigation is, they're not being displayed. Switched back to default theme - here they are, switched to my theme - disappeared.

Any help?